# Conditional sorting, using groupby on columns in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

Consider I have following df.

```
first_primary='N8910-011B0BB' 

dct = {'Store':('19387','19387','19387','19387','19387'),
       'SELF-NBR':('INC1539641','INC1514967','INC1518545','INC1518666','INC1514983'),
       'PARTS_NEW':('N8910-011B0BB','N8910-011B0BB','Q24-FR128043','Q24-FR128043','Q24-FR128042'),
       'date_diff':(1,7,1,1,0),
       'PLACEDAY' :('2020-05-11 18:58:35','2020-05-18 05:25:39','2020-05-12 04:42:29','2020-05-12 02:22:22','2020-05-11 15:20:32')
    }

df = pd.DataFrame(dct)
df['PLACEDAY']= pd.to_datetime(df['PLACEDAY'])

print(df)

    Store   SELF-NBR    PARTS_NEW        date_diff  PLACEDAY
0   19387   INC1539641  N8910-011B0BB       1      2020-05-11 18:58:35
1   19387   INC1514967  N8910-011B0BB       7      2020-05-18 05:25:39
2   19387   INC1518545  Q24-FR128043        1      2020-05-12 04:42:29
3   19387   INC1518666  Q24-FR128043        1      2020-05-12 02:22:22
4   19387   INC1514983  Q24-FR128042        0      2020-05-11 15:20:32
```

Above dataframe `df` is achived from for loop and varies for each unique store_id.
Here data is for store = 19387,  first_primary also varies for each store but will be idenitified by `first_primary` as decribed in the code

I want to conditional sort `df` only if `first_primary` is repeated multiple times,
sort (Descending) the dataframe by `PLACEDAY`, ensuring `first_primary` always stays on the top.

Expected Dataframe

```
    Store   SELF-NBR    PARTS_NEW        date_diff  PLACEDAY
0   19387   INC1514967  N8910-011B0BB       7      2020-05-18 05:25:39
1   19387   INC1539641  N8910-011B0BB       1      2020-05-11 18:58:35
2   19387   INC1518545  Q24-FR128043        1      2020-05-12 04:42:29
3   19387   INC1518666  Q24-FR128043        1      2020-05-12 02:22:22
4   19387   INC1514983  Q24-FR128042        0      2020-05-11 15:20:32
```

Summary:

1. Incase of repeatative `first_primary` in `PARTS_NEW`, `first_primary` with latest time-stamp should be on the top with respective cols('SELF-NBR', 'PARTS_NEW', etc..)
2. If `first_primary` in `PARTS_NEW`, is counted only one time, ensure `first_primary` is
   on the top if the df

Let me know if any more query is required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `sort_values`  + `argsort` with `isin`

```
df = df.sort_values('PLACEDAY',ascending=False)
first_primary='N8910-011B0BB' 
df = df.iloc[(~df.PARTS_NEW.isin([first_primary])).argsort()]
df
   Store    SELF-NBR      PARTS_NEW  date_diff            PLACEDAY
1  19387  INC1514967  N8910-011B0BB          7 2020-05-18 05:25:39
0  19387  INC1539641  N8910-011B0BB          1 2020-05-11 18:58:35
2  19387  INC1518545   Q24-FR128043          1 2020-05-12 04:42:29
3  19387  INC1518666   Q24-FR128043          1 2020-05-12 02:22:22
4  19387  INC1514983   Q24-FR128042          0 2020-05-11 15:20:32
```